# send multiple files to multiple computers in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I need to transfer few files to different computers, 1 file per 1 computer. Now i can only transfer 1 file to 1 computer. Also some computers from my IP pool can be offline, how can i avoid Exception?

Also I have all code in github:
https://github.com/xym4uk/Diplom/tree/master/src/xym4uk/test

> Client

```
package xym4uk.test;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileClient {

private static Socket sock;
private static String fileName;
private static BufferedReader stdin;
private static PrintStream ps;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

public static void sendFile(File myFile) {


    //connecting
    try {
        sock = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to the server, try again later.");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    try {
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

        //Sending file name and file size to the server
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        dos.flush();
        System.out.println("File " + myFile.getName() + " sent to Server.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("File does not exist!");
    }
    DataBase.setRecord(sock.getInetAddress().toString(), myFile.getName());
    try {
        sock.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void receiveFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        sock = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("2");
        ps.println(fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to the server, try again later.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        int bytesRead;
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();

        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

        fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_server_" + fileName));
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();
        in.close();

        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " received from Server.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        sock.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

> Server

```
package xym4uk.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileServer {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        System.out.println("Server started.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Port already in use.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());

            Thread t = new Thread(new CLIENTConnection(clientSocket));

            t.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error in connection attempt.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

> ClientConnection

```
package xym4uk.test;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CLIENTConnection implements Runnable {

private Socket clientSocket;
private BufferedReader in = null;

public CLIENTConnection(Socket client) {
    this.clientSocket = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String clientSelection;
        while ((clientSelection = in.readLine()) != null) {
            switch (clientSelection) {
                case "1":
                    receiveFile();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    String outGoingFileName;
                    while ((outGoingFileName = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sendFile(outGoingFileName);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect command received.");
                    break;
            }
            in.close();
            break;
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void receiveFile() {
    try {
        int bytesRead;

        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_client_" + fileName));
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();
        clientData.close();

        System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from client.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Client error. Connection closed.");
    }
}

public void sendFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        //handle file read
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        //handle file send over socket
        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        //Sending file name and file size to the client
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        dos.flush();
        System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to client.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("File does not exist!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Could you be more specific about the trouble you are having?

Comment: I can't understand how to transfer few files to few computers in 1 cycle

Comment: If you want to transfer the same file to multiple hosts, then you should look at multicast. Otherwise, you should be able to handle an exception for hosts that are no longer on-line. Exceptions are not the enemy; you should always be prepared to correctly handle them.

Comment: @RonMaupin i need to transfer different files to different hosts. I have 1 big file, split it, then transfer parts over network